# Is hardware helping reducing crashes of OS X?

Tags: kernel, osx, drivers, crash

I am taking an OS course this semester, and we mentioned that device drivers can cause about 85% of crashes(for Windows).

My understanding is that: since many personal computers are configured with a variety of hardware, and most device drivers are not very robust when fault happens. Thus Windows crashes a lot, and Linux's driver code also have a lot of bugs.

However, Mac might be a different story. Since all OS X are only available on Mac, and the hardware components of a Mac is relatively constant compared with other PC. Thus Apple may have much higher quality of driver code than other OS does. That's why Mac OS X seems to be more stable than other OS. I wonder if I am correct on this argument.

I don't really know much about Mac, and I haven't found a journal/conference paper talking about crashes of Mac OS X. Please correct my statement if the singularity of hardware is not the reason why OS X seems to be more stable than other OS.

Comment: Is your premise based on any objective criteria, or just on Apple's marketing material?

Comment: Neither. I am just wondering if singularity of hardware can actually help improving the stability of system. Since driver developers only need to focus on a particular device, it's easier for them to write drivers with fewer bugs thus produce more stable system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise is unprovable. Science requires a [falsifiable hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability); there is no way to test any of the likely counterhypotheses, such as that Windows would crash less if Apple wrote all of the drivers instead, or that Windows would be more stable if Microsoft somehow cut off support for a vast chunk of the existing supported hardware space. You'd basically have to restart the history of personal computing and have an omnipotent hand to rearrange the facts to drive toward the conclusion you wish to test.

Nevertheless, I believe there is some truth to this argument.

My personal experience is that Linux, FreeBSD and OS X all kernel panic about the same amount, which is to say "rarely." The vast majority of cases where I have been able to diagnose the reason for crash, it *has* been due to a device driver, but that in turn was due to faulty hardware. When the hardware breaks, it causes the device driver to break, and when something breaks in kernel space, the kernel usually crashes, locks up, or self-diagnoses via some [panic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)/[oops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_oops)/[BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) condition.

As to how that applies to Windows, I think the situation is simply that Windows boxes tend to be built down to an arbitrary price that the marketing department picked. The market is so competitive that corners get cut, so low-end Windows hardware fails more often than happens in our expensive Macs and *ix servers.

You see this often in the *ix worlds. Someone will be complaining about networking problems, then mention that they're using some dodgy on-board MAC chip (RealTek, Broadcom, etc.) and right away, someone will tell them to go get an Intel card.

It is also the case that this extreme price sensitivity in the Windows market means there is less money available for software development talent, so drivers may not be written by the most competent people around. Even when good talent is put on the project, they're going to ship as soon as they've got something that marketing considers sufficiently functional. That team will all be let go, or will go on to another project, so when the 1.0 driver hits the real world and unanticipated problems come up, there isn't a fully-staffed competent development team sitting around to fix those problems.

I mentioned that OS X, FreeBSD and Linux are all roughly comparable in terms of kernel panics per year because it shows that quantity of drivers doesn't explain everything here. Linux has many more drivers than either FreeBSD or OS X, yet it's roughly as stable, as long as you stay away from the really low-end hardware. Linux typically won't run as well on a $500 repurposed Windows PC as on a $1,500 purpose-built Linux server. You're paying for better quality components which cause fewer problems for the driver, which makes it less likely to crash.

If you run Windows on that same $1,500 server, I predict that it will run quite reliably. The days of Windows being unreliable on pretty much all hardware started disappearing with Windows 2000. The problem isn't Windows, *per se* any more, the problem is with the skinflints driving the Windows market. This is also the source of many other ills, such as "freeware" that sneakily installs predatory software in order to funnel money back to the creators.

Another point about your 85% number: that's not surprising, since a huge amount of what a kernel does is run drivers, and the rest of what it does is mostly generic, and therefore extremely well-debugged. When you have 1,000 different NIC chips to support, you can't expect them to be as well-debugged as when you only support 20 NIC chips. And, your restricted set of 20 NIC chip drivers still won't be as well-debugged as, say, the kernel's message passing code.

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated response. I simply assumed that all hardware comes with the same quality, which apparently to be false in reality.